# Program only outputting last element in array list - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently having an issue where when I output my array into an ordered list, it only outputs the very last song in the collection of five.  Any help on how I can make it display all five would be appreciated. (First time trying to use arrays).

```
private void initActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    ArrayList songTitle = new ArrayList();
    Collections.addAll(songTitle, "Pink Floyd - The Dark Side of the Moon", "AC/DC - Back in Black", "Led Zeppelin - Led Zeppelin IV", "Billy Joel - Piano Man", "Eric Clapton - Unplugged");
    Collections.sort(songTitle);
    for (int j = 0; j < songTitle.size(); j++) {
        nameOutput.setText(j + "- " + songTitle.get(j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you expect something like this. ?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("");
for (int j = 0; j < songTitle.size(); j++) {
  sb.append(j);
  sb.append("- ");
  sb.append(songTitle.get(j));
  sb.append(" ");
}
nameOutput.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I believe that was what I was expecting.  Thankyou for the help, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting using setText here

```
for (int j = 0; j < songTitle.size(); j++) {
    nameOutput.setText(j + "- " + songTitle.get(j));
}
```

append string first and then set to `nameOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using arrays properly, but you seem to be overwriting the contents of `nameOutput` each time you go through the loop.